# ajax method return view code instead redirect on view in laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have many buttons in single form that's why i used ajax to call different method on different button click event. But while I call method using ajax and return view, it send code of view as response, And i need to redirect on that view my method code is as below.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   return view('surat.proceed_sell');
}
```

can i redirect on other view using ajax? Or any other way to call different methods on different button click event then please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is return the url where to redirect as a response in your controller as

`return url('the path');`

and in your ajax success callback you could redirect to the view as

`window.location = data;`

The url should be defined in your route file where the view is rendered.

Comment: can i pass post data with `window.location = "{{ route(route.name) }}" + data`

Comment: That wouldn't be post though

Answer (score 0):

You cannot redirect to a view with Ajax because Ajax expects a response. What you should do is redirect to a page instead, using anchors.

First, define your routes

```
Route::get('surat/proceed', 'SuratController@proceed');
```

Then use anchor with a button to go that page. It doesn't matter how many buttons you have in the form, as longs as they are not of type submit, they should not submit the form.

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <a href="/surat/proceed" class="btn btn-default">Go to proceed</a>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

If this does not help you, please, update your question with your form code.

Comment: Show your form. Update your answer.

Comment: i redirect on page usign `window.location` but can i pass post data with `window.location` ??